# Деление на ноль

Tags: c#

Привет! Я использую одну библиотеку с CodePlex, но почему не возникает ошибка или исключение в коде ниже?

```
var speed = 13.9 * 1000 / TimerPeriod * (ts.Seconds + ts.Milliseconds / 1000.0);
sel_probe.SegmentLength = 0;
var proportion = speed / sel_probe.SegmentLength;
// proportion вычисляется, но откуда?
```

Comment: А что, должно? Результат должен получиться вполне нормальный -- бесконечность. Какие тут ошибки? (Если бы данные были целыми, дело другое)

Comment: @alexlz, есть в математике такое правило, что делить на ноль - нельзя. Зная это правило, @alvin задал такой вот вопрос. В данном случае интересно не выходное значение, а свойства компилятора...

Comment: @Asen Ecma-334 C# Language Specification 11.1.6 Floating point types

Comment: @Asen, в *школьной* математике)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, SegmentLength при попытке записать туда 0, молча записывает какое-то ненулевое значение по-умолчанию.

Comment: кароче да, там используются аксессоры.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поставить точку останова на строке

```
var proportion = speed / sel_probe.SegmentLength;
```

Откройте окно watch и в нем посмотрите значение выражений:

```
speed
sel_probe.SegmentLength
speed / sel_probe.SegmentLength
```

Заодно узнаете, какой тип имеет переменная speed:)

Answer (score 2):

А мне чего-то кажется, что все значительно проще. Какое ожидаемое поведение вот в этом случае:

```
double d = 0;
var r = 42/d;
```

`DivideByZeroException`? Ну тогда я вас разочарую, результат - `Infinity`, а не исключение.

Переменная `speed` имеет тип `double`, а его делить на 0 "можно" в том плане, что исключения не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Присваивается ли `sel_probe.SegmentLength` значение "0", скорей всего в классе используется метод, который не позволяет иметь/возвращать значение 0 для `SegmentLength`.

Comment: а в C# разве можно перегружать операторы?

Comment: можно но не все. да, я не учел что оператор присвоения нельзя перегружать в C#. исправил.

Comment: это называется не метод. это называется аксессоры getter и setter